# Labels changing on form

Tags: c#, label

So when I select an option from my combo box like miles to feet. I want my labels to change also. So I have two labels and the default is miles to km. I want it to change as it corresponds to what I select in the combo box. How do i go about that?

Comment: windows or web? which technology? which language?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. For anyone to be able to help you, you need to give a lot more details on what platform you are using, the code that you've already tried etc. Please edit your question with additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the combo box in design, this will generate an event like comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged, and enter some code:

```
switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        label1.Text = "km";
        break;
    case 1:
        label1.Text = "miles";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the constructor(after initializecomponent);

```
 this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ComboBox1SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Then the changecode

```
 void ComboBox1SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        switch(comboBox1.Text)
            {
               case "miles to km" :
               label2.text="km";
               label1.text=milesvalue;//whatever you want in km
               break;

               case "miles to feet" :
               label2.text="feet";
               label1.text=feetvalue;//whatever you want in feet
               break;
               // and so on...
            }   
    }
```

Hope it works. Next time try searching things yourself

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about a windows form.

First you have to add values to the combo box's items collection (either on the properties window or programmatically).

Select the combo box's selected index changed event on the properties window where the events are. Double click on "selected index changed"

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = this.Text;
}
```

To add values to the combo box programmatically, enter this code in the InitializeComponent method of your form designer.

```
    this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
    "item 1",
    "item 2",
    "item 3"});
```